# Angular 8 Firestore accessing all values in a subcollection

Tags: angular, typescript, google-cloud-firestore

Im a little confused on Firestore structuring.

If I have a collection 'Users'/ + uid,(I'm using the user id for firebase authentication for the document id), then I have a subcollection under that named flashCards.

How would I access the properties of that subcollection to using ngfor to show them all on the screen?

Comment: Accessing a subcollection is quite similar to accessing a top-level collection. See the documentation for it [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model#subcollections). If you've tried that, but are having problems making it work, edit your question to include the [minimal, complete/standalone code that reproduces where you got stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I figured out the issue. It was like you said, just had to go further down the path.